# For loop adaption

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot

I have two column vectors 'a' and 'b' (e.g. as follows)

```
 a_o = [4 5 6]'
 b_o = [1 8 4]'
```

now I want to create a for loop in which no of iterations can be defined as

```
   for
      i=1:1:20   
   end
```

What I want to do in loop is as follow in table for each value of a_o and respective b_o. It should take first the first value of 'a_o' and 'b_o' (in this case a-o1= 4 and b_o1=1) as in loop and do calculations for 20 iterations of i. like in table below

```
    a            b             c                     No. of iterations
   a1=a_o1      b1=b_o1       c1=a_o1xb_o1           1
   a2=a1+c1     b2=b1-c1      c2=a2xb2               2
   a3=a2+c2     b3=b2-c2      c3=a2xb2               3
   .            .             .                      .
   .            .             .                      .
   .            .             .                      .
   a20=a19+c19  b20=b19-c19   c20=a19xb19            20
```

After this it should take second value of 'a_o' and 'b_o' (in this case a-o1= 5 and b_o1=8) and repeat the procedure, as mentioned above in table. Similarly for rest of 'a_o' and 'b_o'.
Also when loop is finished, there is a figure required which will be x-y plot between y-axis = 'a' and x-axis= 'no. of iterations'. In this case I expect three curves as there are three value in a_o and each curve have 20 data points as 'no. of iteration' is 20.

I need suggestions, as my actual requirement is not as simple as stated above. It contains very large data set. Also a different approach can be adapted.

Comment: Do you want somebody to write that loop or to come up with proposal how to make it faster than with a simple loop?

Comment: @Sebastian:Thanks It would be very helpful if you write loop, as I am not an expert in loops and most likely end up with some mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact quite straightforward, however I refuse to make so many variables, instead we just make a few bigger ones:

```
n = 20;
a_o = [4 5 6]';
b_o = [1 8 4]';
c_o = a_o.*b_o; % You may want to do the regular multiplication

%Initialize your matrices
a = repmat(a_o,1,n);
b = repmat(b_o,1,n);
c = repmat(c_o,1,n);

for t = 2:n
  a(:,t) =  a(:,t-1)+c(:,t-1);
  b(:,t) =  b(:,t-1)-c(:,t-1);
  c(:,t) =  a(:,t).*b(:,t);
end
```

This should do approximately what you want and shouldn't be too hard to adjust.